# Activity not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I created a broadcast reciever that creates a notification, by clicking a notification an activity launched, that activity is launching but I couldnt able to view it, I am using the following code:

```
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (notificationManager == null) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setTicker("Its Ticker")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
            .setContentText("Its Content")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context, NotificationDialog.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK),0));
    notificationManager.notify("interstitial_tag", 0, builder.getNotification());

}
```

Note: `NotificationDialog.java` is my activity, this activity is running as I debugged but not viewing. trying for hours but couldnot find any answer, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Try: `.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context, NotificationDialog.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),0));`

Comment: Thank you that worked. post it as answer, so I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** instead of **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**

```
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (notificationManager == null) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setTicker("Its Ticker")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
            .setContentText("Its Content")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context, NotificationDialog.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),0));
    notificationManager.notify("interstitial_tag", 0, builder.getNotification());

}
```